# What literary device is "the footsteps hesitated" an example of?

Tags: literary-device

I know that people are not the only ones who hesitate, so it isn't personification. But "hesitate" is a word which I would normally associate with sentient beings. So what literary device is "the footsteps hesitated" an example of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the senses three dictionaries list

> {[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hesitate)} **hesitate**
>   intr.v. ...
>
> 1. To pause or wait in uncertainty: She hesitated for a second before opening the door.
> 2. To be slow to act, speak, or decide: "I have for many months hesitated about the propriety of allowing this, or any part of my
>      narrative, to come before the public eye, until after my death"
>      (Thomas De Quincey).
> 3. To be reluctant: hesitated to pick up the pan, fearing it was hot.

...........

> {[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition
>   2014](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hesitate)} **hesitate** vb
>   (intr)
>
> 1. to hold back or be slow in acting; be uncertain
> 2. to be unwilling or reluctant (to do something)
> 3. to stammer or pause in speaking

..............

> {[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hesitate)} **hesitate** v.
>
> v.i.
>
> 1. to be reluctant to act because of fear, indecision, or disinclination.
> 2. to have scruples or doubts about something.
> 3. to stop for a moment; pause.
> 4. to stammer.
>
> v.t.
>
> 5. to have scruples or doubts about: He hesitated to break the law.

we see that one of the dictionaries does actually include the sense not requiring a volitional agent (Webster's; sense 3).

This is a broadening of the application of a word. It might be called a transference (the person, not in the first instance the footsteps, hesitate, showing uncertainty, reluctance or whatever) here. I wouldn't say that 'metonymy' or 'synechdoche' really apply here. And it's perhaps too close a connection for 'personification' as usually used. It's not as if we're expected to use our imaginations to consider footsteps as having volition as we are with Lightning McQueen say; it's more like the use of a transferred epithet, 'a contemplative pint'.

The relevant descriptor (I'm not sure whether I should say 'term') in linguistics is 'increase in semantic range' (see [Productive lexical processes in present-day English ... Raymond Hickey 9.4](https://www.uni-due.de/~lan300/13_Productive_Lexical_Processes_in_Present-day_English_(Hickey).pdf)).

Aa article I find very relevant, although the source's authority has been queried (though on ideological grounds) is [The Great Soviet Encyclopedia (1979)](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Transferred+Meaning+of+a+Word).

> **Transferred Meaning of a Word**
>
> ... [T]he [/A] secondary, or derived, meaning of a word, [is] connected with its
>   basic, main meaning by a metonymic or metaphorical relationship or by
>   some associative features. The transferred meaning of a word can arise
>   from spatial, temporal, or logical correspondences in concepts, such
>   as the contiguity of material and product or of process and result....

If one accepts the term 'transference', metonymy, metaphor, or even a looser association is the underlying factor. I'd say that 'a *proud* day', a *quiet* drink and 'the footsteps *hesitated*' are examples involving the looser association.

Comment: This is a very detailed and interesting analysis, Edwin! It seems that there is no clear-cut answer to my question, but I agree that this appears to be an example of "increase in semantic range" of the word 'hesitate'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an instance of [personification](http://literarydevices.net/personification/). Here the footsteps (things) behave like a human being:

> - is a figure of speech in which a thing, an idea or an animal is given human attributes. The non-human objects are portrayed in such a way that we feel they have the ability to act like human beings.

Comment: I'm confused because non-humans can hesitate too.